# How do you make Music shuffle on Android Studio? Using or without using arrays

Tags: android-studio, libgdx

I need help making the songs Shuffle (mixed) but I don't know how and also I want it to go to another music each time without repeating.

```
public class MusicMix {

    private Music music1, music2, music3, music4, music5,music6,music7,music8,music9,music10,music11,music12,music13,music14,music15,music16,music17;

    music1 = Gdx.audio.newMusic(Gdx.files.internal("musicA.mp3"));
    music2 = Gdx.audio.newMusic(Gdx.files.internal("musicB.mp3"));
    music3 = Gdx.audio.newMusic(Gdx.files.internal("musicC.mp3"));
    music4 = Gdx.audio.newMusic(Gdx.files.internal("musicD.mp3"));
    music5 = Gdx.audio.newMusic(Gdx.files.internal("musicE.mp3"));
    music6 = Gdx.audio.newMusic(Gdx.files.internal("musicF.mp3"));
    music7 = Gdx.audio.newMusic(Gdx.files.internal("musicG.mp3"));
    music8 = Gdx.audio.newMusic(Gdx.files.internal("musicH.mp3"));
    music9 = Gdx.audio.newMusic(Gdx.files.internal("musicJ.mp3"));
    music10 = Gdx.audio.newMusic(Gdx.files.internal("musicK.mp3"));
    music11 = Gdx.audio.newMusic(Gdx.files.internal("musicL.mp3"));
    music12 = Gdx.audio.newMusic(Gdx.files.internal("musicM.mp3"));
    music13 = Gdx.audio.newMusic(Gdx.files.internal("musicN.mp3"));
    music14 = Gdx.audio.newMusic(Gdx.files.internal("musicO.mp3"));
    music15 = Gdx.audio.newMusic(Gdx.files.internal("musicP.mp3"));
    music16 = Gdx.audio.newMusic(Gdx.files.internal("musicQ.mp3"));
    music17 = Gdx.audio.newMusic(Gdx.files.internal("musicR.mp3"));
 }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519736/random-shuffling-of-an-array

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Random shuffling of an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519736/random-shuffling-of-an-array)

Comment: I don't think you want to be loading more than two or three musics at once on Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all create first an array that should make your life easier. Instead of manually doing it one by one.

```
Array<Music> musics = new Array<Music>();
        for (int i = 65; i < 25; i++) {
            //The ascii of 65 = A
            char ascii = (char) i;
            Music music = Gdx.audio.newMusic(Gdx.files.internal("music" + ascii + ".mp3"));
            musics.add(music);
        }
```

Then after that just call this method. It's a built-in method in Libgdx. This method should answer your question.

```
        musics.shuffle();
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to implement your requirement in this way.

```
public class TestGame extends Game {

    private Array<String> musicName;
    private Array<Music> musicList;
    private IntArray intArray;

    @Override
    public void create() {

        musicName=new Array<String>(new String[]{"sound/x1.ogg","sound/x2.ogg","sound/x3.ogg","sound/x4.ogg","sound/x5.ogg"});
        musicList=new Array<Music>();
        intArray=new IntArray();

        for (String path:musicName) {

            Music music=Gdx.audio.newMusic(Gdx.files.internal(path));
            musicList.add(music);
            intArray.add(musicName.indexOf(path,true));
            music.setOnCompletionListener(new OnComplete(this));
        }

        int value=MathUtils.random(musicList.size-1);
        intArray.removeValue(value);
        musicList.get(value).play();

    }

    public class OnComplete implements Music.OnCompletionListener {
        private TestGame testGame;
        public OnComplete(TestGame game){
            testGame=game;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(Music music) {
            testGame.playUnPlayedMusic();
        }
    }

    public void playUnPlayedMusic(){

        int value ;
        if(intArray.size>0) {
            value = intArray.get(MathUtils.random(intArray.size - 1));
            intArray.removeValue(value);

        }else {
            for (int i=0;i<musicList.size;i++)
                intArray.add(i);

            value = intArray.get(MathUtils.random(intArray.size - 1));
            intArray.removeValue(value);
        }

        Music music= musicList.get(value);
        music.play();
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {

    }
}
```